# Angular Typescript $event.target.value

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to go through the Adam Freeman angular book, but many of the example don't work, I imagine due to new changes since it was written.

The issue I have is the following template doesn't work due to typescript not liking the event.target

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="selectedProduct=$event.target.value">
```

[image]

The selectedProduct is declared in the template component as show below (

```
export class ProductComponent {
    selectedProduct: string = "";
}
```

I then tried this by casting it as a HTMLTextAreaElement but then it says possibly undefined

[image]

I also tried with the !

[image]

If anyone could explain how I get this to work that would be great as it seems like pulling teeth, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  [$any()](https://angular.io/guide/template-expression-operators#the-any-type-cast-function) type cast function.

**Try this:**

```
  <input type="text"  class="form-control" (input)="selectedProduct=$any($event).target.value">
```

Comment: Thank you this at least worked, much appreciated, the next part of the book goes into using [(ngModel)] which then means I dont have to do this, but useful to get it working, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

This issues is not about angular and it's about typescript. This feature is called `strict null checks` and you can turn it off by `strictNullChecks` to false in `tsconfig` file.

But better way is to use `Optional chaining` (see [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html)) that is a means to access properties on possibly null or undefined reference.

Note that you need typescript version be 3.7 or later for Optional chaining:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" (input)="selectedProduct=$event?.target?.value">
```

Comment: Thanks I believe I am using this 3.7 as that is what is installed in this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.7 but the ? still cause the issue "Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'."